# Cardinality of sets of Cauchy sequences

Tags: gm.general-mathematics

What is the cardinality of the set of all Cauchy sequences made by rational numbers?And why would that be so?

Comment: This is not of research level, but let me answer it here: the cardinality in question is at most $(2^\omega)^\omega=2^\omega$, upon considering all real sequences. But clearly it is also at least $2^\omega$, upon considering a distinct rational Cauchy sequence for each real number (converging to the number). So the cardinality in question is $2^\omega$ (the cardinality of real numbers). Next time, ask such questions at https://math.stackexchange.com/